# how do you define a method with a "." that extends the functionality of a preexisting attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

So, this is what I have so far:

```
  # @return [Array<Hash>] of variables ([Placeholders, actual variables])
  def variables
      # @return [Hash] of all variables. 
      #     If actual variables are named teh same as the placeholders, the placeholders will be over written.
      #     This implementation of merging hashes of an array will work even if we add more elements to the 
      #     variables array.
      self.class.send(:define_method, "variables.flatten") do
        return self.variables.inject{|placeholders, vars| placeholders.merge(vars || {})}
      end

    return [placeholder_variables, self.variable_data]
  end
```

I want to be able to do:

```
my_object.variables # => return the Array<Hash>
```

but also be able to do

```
my_object.variables.flatten # => return a single merged hash
```

the issue when I just do

```
def variables.flatten
```

is that when I run the console, I get an error message saying that `variables` is not defined (or just whatever I put before `.flatten`)

is there a way I can define my custom `.flatten` method only on the `variables` attribute? (normal `<Array>.flatten` doesn't work here, cause I need the hashes merged. )

Comment: create a dedicated class. can't see another elegant option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer: define the method in its own module, then include it in the array you return:

```
module SpecialFlatten
  def flatten
    first.update last
  end
end
```

...and later...

```
def variables
  vals = [placeholder_variables, self.variable_data]
  return vals.extend(SpecialFlatten)
end
```

But in this case, a better option might be to do this:

```
def variables(*flags)
  if flags.include? :flatten
    placeholder_variables.update self.variable_data
  else
    [placeholder_variables, self.variable_data]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to define the "variables.flatten" method. To prove that let's check by this example:

```
require 'ruby_parser'

RubyParser.new.parse(<<-EOF)
  my_object.variables.flatten
EOF
#=> s(:call,
 s(:call, s(:call, nil, :my_object, s(:arglist)), :variables, s(:arglist)),
 :flatten,
 s(:arglist))
```

As you can see `variables` and `flatten` are different tokens and they can't merge into one token, that's a parse issue.

But one thing maybe you're missing - that's the chainability. The method `variables` returns the array of variables and if they are responding to flatten method, the result will be flat. If they're not responding to that method, you should implement `flatten` method for these objects.

Comment: Excellent illustration with RubyParser

Comment: Of course, it's possible to define that method. The OP's code does just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a singleton method on the returning value.

```
def variables
  result = [placeholder_variables, self.variable_data]
  # redefine method flatten on the result array
  def result.flatten
    # did not understand what you are trying to do here
    # self is the array here
    inject{|placeholders, vars| placeholders.merge(vars || {})}
  end
  return result # return the array with added method
end
```

However, this is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array#flatten` method is part of Ruby core, so I would recommend not changing it, especially if you are working on a team with other developers.  It seems like you are trying to conform to an existing interface.  I'd look for alternatives, but you could override the flatten method on the return value of the `variables` method.

```
def variables
  [placeholder_variables, self.class.variable_data].tap do |vars|
    vars.instance_eval do
      def flatten
        inject{|result, vars_hash| result.merge!(vars_hash)}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: [placeholder_variables, self.class.variable_data] is already an array, I think the flatten method should be defined for every element in array if they don't respond to it.

Comment: @megas, what you are describing would only work if the OP wanted to do something like `variables.map(&:flatten)`.  Instead the OP really wants to override `#flatten` to do an inject which merges all the elements of the array (Hash instances).  E.g. If #variables returns `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}]` then calling #flatten on that result should return `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`.